# Created NuGet package does not have any compile time assemblies

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I've created a NuGet package from a class library project following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-dotnet-cli). The instructions are for using the dotnet cli.

I used `dotnet pack` to create the package and `nuget add` to add it to a local repository.

When I install the package in another project I find that I cannot access the namespaces of my package. But the namespaces of the dependencies of my package are available.

It seems to be due to the fact that my package does not publish its own compile time assemblies but the dependencies do.

How can I create the package properly using the commands above?

Other info:

myProject.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <PackageId>MyPackageHelpers</PackageId>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Authors>My Name</Authors>
    <Company>My company</Company>
    <Description>
        This client library does X.
    </Description>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup" Version="3.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.7.3.19" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Using `dotnet pack`

1. `cd` to the folder with the code for your project.
2. Execute `dotnet pack`

Using `nuget add`

1. `cd` to the folder containing your `.nupkg` file.
2. Execute `nuget add your_package_id.1.0.0.nupkg -source "D:\my_local_nuget_package_folder"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To publish the package to a local folder properly use `nuget push`.

`nuget push your_package_id.1.0.0.nupkg -source "D:\my_local_nuget_package_folder"`

If using `nuget add` must use the `-expand` option.

`nuget add your_package_id.1.0.0.nupkg -source "D:\my_local_nuget_package_folder" -expand`

These commands will create the package folder properly with a libs folder containing the necessary dlls.